# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined google maps

Tags: c#, jquery, google-maps

I want to use Geo location, but there is $ is not defined google maps. the code is as below:

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>
```

API Code

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAV8AiebjdcoS-Ratewz-HDkFt7XCq3zOM&libraries=places&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Scrpirt

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#doctorlocation').goMap({
                maptype: 'ROADMAP',
                latitude: 40.760651,
                longitude: -73.930635,
                zoom: 6,
                scaleControl: true,
                scrollwheel: false,
                markers: [
                    {
                        latitude: 40.716818, longitude: -73.983164, group: 'doctor', icon: 'http://medical.vanuston.com/images/map/doctor.png', html: {
                            content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.<br /><a href="company-page.html">Read More</a>'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });
        });
```

Comment: Because you forget to add the jquery library in your code

Comment: @MayankPandeyz i added Code already in master page <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [$.goMap()](http://www.pittss.lv/jquery/gomap/) .So go through it.

and also div is also wrong .
Instead of

`<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>`

it will be

`<div id="doctorlocation"></div>` as `id` is `doctorlocation` in initialization

```js
$(function() {
  $('#doctorlocation').goMap({
    maptype: 'ROADMAP',
    latitude: 40.760651,
    longitude: -73.930635,
    zoom: 6,
    scaleControl: true,
    scrollwheel: false,
    markers: [{
      latitude: 40.716818,
      longitude: -73.983164,
      group: 'doctor',
      icon: 'http://medical.vanuston.com/images/map/doctor.png',
      html: {
        content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.<br /><a href="company-page.html">Read More</a>'
      }
    }]
  });
});
```

```css
#doctorlocation {
  width: 700px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="doctorlocation"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAV8AiebjdcoS-Ratewz-HDkFt7XCq3zOM&libraries=places"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.pittss.lv/jquery/gomap/js/jquery.gomap-1.3.3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

That error can only be caused by one of three things:

```
1) Your JavaScript file is not being properly loaded into your page
2) You have a botched version of jQuery. This could happen because someone edited the core file, or a plugin may have overwritten the $ variable.
3) You have JavaScript running before the page is fully loaded, and as such, before jQuery is fully loaded.
```

Either Put the jquery.js before your script tag and it will work ;)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
```